# Eclipse plug-in is loaded on Windows and Linux but not on MacOS

Tags: eclipse-plugin

My Eclipse plug-in adds a category in the File - New - Other... dialog and provides a wizard for adding new projects. It is developed on MacOS 11.1, JDK 15.01, Eclipse 2020-09, and runs in the debugger without problems. The plug-in does only depend on standard plugins:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: wim.ix Plugin 
Bundle-SymbolicName: de.wim.ix.dev.eclipse.plugin;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 20.0.1.14
Bundle-Activator: de.wim.ix.dev.eclipse.plugin.Activator
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.ui.ide;bundle-version="3.17.200",
 org.eclipse.core.resources;bundle-version="3.13.800",
 org.eclipse.pde.core;bundle-version="3.14.0"
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-11
Automatic-Module-Name: de.wim.ix.dev.eclipse.plugin
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Bundle-ClassPath: lib/wim.ixClient.jar,
 lib/slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar,
 .,
 lib/commons-io-2.6.jar,
 lib/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar,
 lib/logback-core-1.2.3.jar,
 lib/commons-compress-1.20.jar,
 lib/gson-2.8.6.jar
Bundle-Vendor: wim.ix
```

and all further required jars are included in the plugin-jar.

I follow [this tutorial, 20ff](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePlugin/article.html#exercise-create-a-feature-for-your-plug-in), to create an update site from where the plug-in (resp. feature) can be installed.

On Windows and Linux with the same JDK an Eclipse versions, the installation works fine. The category in File - New - Other... is shown and the wizard dialog can be started.

Installing the feature into the Eclipse on MacOS - where it has been built and debugged before -  does not show an error too. Howerver, the **category does not appear** in the File - New - Other... window. The feature is listed in Eclipse - About - Installation Details... as installed software but is not found as installed plugin.

If the plugin is copied into the Eclipse/dropins folder, the result is very similar: It works on Windows and Linux. It does not work on MacOS.

Is there anything special to do on MacOS for importing a feature/plugin?

Comment: No, there is nothing special for macOS. If you have installed the plug-in before you will need to update the Bundle-Version to make sure the new version is used - only the first 3 parts of the version are considered or try starting with `-clean`

Comment: Most likely it is related to the dropins folder. If a plugin is updated there (3rd version part changes) the plugin is no more loaded. I have observed different effects after updating: compile errors in my projects due to "org.eclipse" not found, errors at Preferences - Plugin D... - Target ... where the old plugin version is still referenced. All those buttons Remove, Add, Reload etc. there do not help. The only solution I found is uninstall, remove ~/.eclise and ~/.p2 and install again. So, my recommendation: do not use the dropins folder on MacOS